# JavaScript Async Function Usage For Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, async-await, automation

I am very new to JavaScript Async & Await concept. I am trying to build a Chrome extension which helps with searching a coop number in Amazon website.

I have created an async function which executes one step after the other (ex: clicking on a button, entering a text, loading a different page of amazon etc.,). **Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_Single** is the function which works fine for a single account.

Now I want to execute this function for multiple accounts one after the other based on the search result of the function. I created **Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_MainLoop** for this purpose. However, the loop logic does not work.

Please advise me on how to proceed any hints or suggestions would help.

```
function Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_MainLoop() {

  //Account_Names.forEach( (account)  => {
  //});
  const Account_Names = ["CA - Misfit Wearables", "Apparel and Accessories", "Handbags"];

  for (i = 0; i < Account_Names.length; i++) {
    alert(Account_Names[i]);
    Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_Single(Account_Names[i]);
  }

}
async function Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_Single(account) {
  var response;

  //alert("First Account Loop Start - " + account);
  // Load Account Switcher      

  //Perform_Action("Load_Page", VCA_Home, VCA_Switcher, null);  
  response = await Perform_Action("Load_Page", VCA_Home, VCA_Switcher, null);
  response.success ? op = (response.data) : op = (response.data);
  console.log("Load_Page - " + response.data);

  // Select Account Button Click

  Obj_XPath = "//button[ text() = 'Select account ']"
  response = await Perform_Action("Click_Action", VCA_Switcher, Obj_XPath, null)
  response.success ? op = (response.data) : op = (response.data);


  Obj_XPath = "//textarea[@id = 'search-input']"
  response = await Perform_Action("Set_Text", VCA_CooP, Obj_XPath, Coop_Number)
  response.success ? op = (response.data) : op = (response.data);
  //alert("First Account Loop Done");


  Obj_XPath = "//button[@id = 'search-button-announce']"
  response = await Perform_Action("Click_Action", VCA_CooP, Obj_XPath, null)
  response.success ? op = (response.data) : op = (response.data);

  return 0;
}

function Perform_Action(featureName, curr_page_Url, param1, param2) {

  var request = {
    feature: featureName,
    curr_page_Url: curr_page_Url,
    param1: param1,
    param2: param2
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(chrome_Ext_ID, request, (response) => {
      if (response.success) {
        resolve(response)
      } else {
        reject(response)
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I have been searching online for the solution, people said foreach does not work. So I am trying For loop but it still doesn't work. Please help me out this is a very important project for me.

Comment: What exactly does not work in the loop? Could you explain your current output and your desired output?

Comment: `await Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_Single(Account_Names[i]);`

Comment: Something that may help you would be [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if you want multiple promises to settle before continuing. If you need to wait for one promise to finish before beginning the next, then `Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_MainLoop` should be an `async` function and you should replace `Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_Single(Account_Names[i])` with `await Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_Single(Account_Names[i])` in order to "wait" for the promise to settle before continuing

Comment: Hi @Rojo, I was expecting the For Loop to run the function "Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_Single" for single account, complete the function then execute the function for the next account in the array. What's happening here is the For loop displays (alert) for all accounts. Then only for the last item in the array the function is being called.

Comment: Hi @Konrad, I did try making the MainLoop function as async and using await as you had suggested. However I get the error "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules chrome extension". Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Comment: Make the function asnyc: `async function Find_Account_For_CooPNumber_MainLoop` like your other function

Comment: Hi @Rojo,  I did it. That's when I get the error - "await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules chrome extension"

Comment: Can you update your post to reflect your current code?